# Sorting Hex color codes with increasing gradient

Tags: javascript, php, colors, hex

I have a problem, i got few thousands of color codes RGB and Respective Hex values, I want to sort them to increasing order based on color intensity. I have found few methods to do so, but unable to understand how to implement them, can any one help me to guide how to make it work.

solution 1:-
[javascript method](http://www.runtime-era.com/2011/11/grouping-html-hex-colors-by-hue-in.html)

solution 2:-

[php method](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4598.html)

please note i have no expireance in php or javascript. but i have working wamp server, knows html.

many thanks in advance

Comment: how to make it work is the issue

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to implement the script.
Personnally I did not implement a script, I just used the results of the script from solution 1.

As shown in one comment on the blog, you must have an array of your color objects for input. For example :

```
var unsortedArrayOfColorObjects= [{"hex":"#c6deea"},{"hex":"#c37751"},{"hex":"#83575a"},{"hex":"#dcc896"},{"hex":"#c37751"}, {"hex":"#8e5a64"},{"hex": "#5f233c"}, {"hex":"#3d8e33"}, {"hex":"#a01437"},{"hex":"#ff5f00"}, {"hex":"#000000"}, {"hex":"#698c41"}, {"hex":"#002b7f"}, {"hex":"#b6b8b8"}, {"hex":"#82c8b4"}, {"hex":"#596d9e"},{"hex": "#4d0021"}];
```

then, you can call the function from the script. Like this :

```
sortColors(unsortedArrayOfColorObjects);
```

If you want to get the object values as a string. I will use:

```
 JSON.stringify. JSON.stringify(sortColors(unsortedArrayOfColorObjects));
```

To execute the javascript script, I used the built-in console from Chrome.